# NuxtJS redirect after login

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxtjs and Laravel Passport.  If a user goes to /someurl, but the login method pushes to '/' how do I store /someurl in the session so that I can push to the session variable when logging in?   I have a session variable that is called, but it get's refreshed in the authentication middleware. 
I'm clearly missing something.
Here is my code: in `auth.js` middleware file

```
export default function ({ route, store, redirect }) {
let params = ''
if (!route.path.startsWith('/login') && !route.path.startsWith('/assets') && route.path !== '/') {
    store.state.requestUrl = route.path
}
if (!store.state.authenticated) {
    return redirect('/login')
}
```

and login

```
await this.$store.dispatch('login', {
    username: this.loginDetails.username,
    password: this.loginDetails.password
})
    this.$router.push(this.$store.state.requestUrl) // this is always '/'
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    this.failedLogin = true
}
```

Comment: Redirect will do a server side redirect with lost of current vuex state

Answer (score 2):

The fix for me was simple
in `login.vue` exports remove the line `auth:false` which is used to ignore routing

Answer (score 1):

You need to change a state (store.state.requestUrl) using mutation (`dispatch` method in store - you used it already in `this.$store.dispatch('login')`). So you need to write a mutation changing a state in the store, eg. `this.$store.dispatch('set_request_url', requestUrl)`.

BTW: There is a module for authentication in Nuxt :) https://auth.nuxtjs.org/
I recommend to use it! But if I wanted to implement it by my own I would store a redirect url in cookies (cause it is more durable than vuex).
Nuxt has a module for storing in cookies: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt, but you can also use a vuejs cookies module: https://github.com/alfhen/vue-cookie

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
this.$router.push({path: "panel"})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use @nuxtjs/auth and @nuxtjs/auth-next, You nedd to add this configuration to your nuxt.config.js file:

```
auth{
redirect: {
      login: "/user/login",//this example of the path of login page in your project
      logout: "/", //this will redirect to your home after logout
      home: "/user/account" //this example will redirect to the path of user account page in your project.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.
.
.


        data: () => ({

          previousPage:null,

        }),
        beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
          next(vm => {
            vm.previousPage = from
          })
        },
    created(){
       console.log(this.previousPage.name);
    }
.
.
.
```

Try this