# How to auto-login or redirect?

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm not using `@nuxtjs/auth`, just plain code...

I have a client plugin to auto-login a user upon page-refresh

```js
// FILE ./plugins/auth.client.js
export default async function ({ $axios, store, redirect, route }) {
    console.log('[PLUGIN] Auth (Client)')

    try {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('sc-token')
        store.commit('auth/setAuth', token)

        if (!token) {
            console.log('redirecting... 1')
            return redirect(401, '/auth/login?1')
        }

        const user = await $axios.$post('/api/auth/verify', token)
        console.log('USER', user)

        if (!user) {
            console.log('redirecting... 2')
            return redirect(401, '/auth/login?2')
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return redirect(401, '/auth/login')
    }
}
```

and it's correctly set up as `plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/auth.client' }]` in `nuxt.config.js`

my issue is that `redirect()` only works if it runs in server-side and if I can only access `localStorage` in client-mode, plus, the server always runs first, but I'm trying to attach the token prior to knowing if I need to redirect or not

How do you guys do this?

Comment: Hi could you see this https://dev.to/jackabox/handling-redirects-in-nuxt-js-through-middleware-413p and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850230/nuxtjs-redirect-after-login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally got it all working as intended, had to have a `./plugins/auth.js` in combination with `./middleware/authenticated.js` both with exact same code

`./middleware/authenticated.js` will run for every route change (great to check token validation)

`./plugins.js` runs on client and server as it runs when user refreshes the page

to make all working with those 2 files I had to:

- stop using localStorage and use cookie instead
- use `cookie-universal-nuxt` package
- it will give you `this.$cookies` and will work on middleware either it runs in client-mode or server-mode

for each route change, the middleware verifies token (for tempering, expiration, etc)
when age refreshes, plugin checks the same

code for `./plugins/auth.js`

```js
export default async function ({ $axios, store, redirect, app }) {
    console.log('[PLUGIN] Auth (Server/Client)', process.client)

    const path = app && app.router && app.router.currentRoute ? app.router.currentRoute.fullPath : ''

    try {
        const token = app.$cookies.get('sc-token')
        const isLoggedIn = store.getters['auth/isLoggedIn']

        // console.log('[PLUGIN] Auth: token', token)
        // console.log('[PLUGIN] Auth: isLoggedIn', isLoggedIn)

        // token exists?
        if (!token) {
            store.commit('auth/clearAuth')
            return redirect(`/auth/login?path=${path}&err=no_token`)
        }

        // verify token
        try {
            // $axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
            const user = await $axios.$post('/api/auth/verify', { token })

            // console.log('[PLUGIN] Auth RES OK', user.verified, isLoggedIn)
            // all OK
            if (user.verified && !isLoggedIn) {
                console.log('SETTING AUTH', token)
                store.commit('auth/setAuth', token)
                // return redirect(path)
            }
        } catch (err1) {
            console.log('[PLUGIN] Auth ERROR (1)', err1.message)
            // console.log('redirecting... 2', err1.response.data)

            let message = err1.message
            if (
                err1.response &&
                err1.response.data &&
                err1.response.data.error &&
                err1.response.data.error === 'jwt expired'
            )
                message = 'token_expired'

            store.commit('auth/clearAuth')
            return redirect(`/auth/login?path=${path}&err=${message}`)
        }

        // console.log('COOKIES END')
    } catch (err2) {
        console.log('[PLUGIN] Auth ERROR (2)', err2.message)
        return redirect(401, `/auth/login?err=${err2.message}`)
    }
}
```

my `/auth/verify` API route:

```js
const verifyToken = (req, res) => {
    const token = req.body.token || req.headers.authorization.replace('Bearer ', '')

    try {
        const verified = jwt.verify(token, SECRET_SIGN, { issuer: 'https://auth.domain.com/the-editor' })
        res.json({ verified })
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(401).json({ error: err.message })
    }
}
```

then, my ExpressJs Middleware to verify the token for every call as well to attach the token payload to the request (so I can pick up in the calls later on)

```js
const authentication = (req, res, next) => {
    // authentication
    const url = req.url
    let token = req.body.token || req.headers.authorization || req.headers.cookie

    // console.log('[Authentication Express Middleware] headers', JSON.stringify(req.headers))
    // console.log('[Authentication Express Middleware] cookie', JSON.stringify(req.headers.cookie))
    // console.log('[Authentication Express Middleware] body', JSON.stringify(req.body))
    // console.log('[Authentication Express Middleware]', url, !!token)

    // bypass URL as there's no token yet...
    if (['/auth/login'].includes(url)) return next()

    // not the login path, we should validate token
    if (token) {
        if (token.includes('sc-token=')) token = token.replace('sc-token=', '')

        // check and validate token
        token = token.indexOf('Bearer ') === 0 ? token.substring(7) : token // "Bearer ..."
        return jwt.verify(token, SECRET_SIGN, (err, payload) => {
            // attach payload to user (will be null if not verified)
            req.user = payload

            // if verified, err is null and will continue to the next middleware
            return next(err)
        })
    }

    return next(new Error('No valid token was passed'))
}
```